# ¿Cómo puedo redirigir a los usuarios a diferentes páginas basado en datos de la sesión en PHP al darle clic a una imagen?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Hay dos usuarios (administrador y cliente).

Dentro de la página que el cliente ve tengo una imagen donde si es un cliente el quien le de clic lo mande a su "home"(TENDA.PHP).

Si es el administrador que lo mande al "home"(administrador.php) del administrador; les dejo el código que está dentro de *.php

```
...
<div class="col-md-4 top-header-middle">
                    <a href="#" onclick="direc();"><img src="img/1.png" alt="" width="80%"/></a>
                    <script>
                    function direc(){
                            if (<?$_SESSION["tper1"];?> === 'admin'){
                                 header("location:administrador.php");
                            }
                            else (<?$_SESSION["tper1"];?> === 'client'){
                                  header("location:tienda.php");
                            }

        }
                    </script>
                </div>
...
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: ¿Cual es el error aquí?. Aparte creo que no deberías hacer el re direccionamiento con una imagen, creo que la pregunta se formulo mal y pues de preferencia pon el problema que te sale al ejecutar ese codigo

Comment: Usa `'<?$_SESSION["tper1"];?>'` en lugar de `<?$_SESSION["tper1"];?>`, al imprimir el valor de las variables PHP para que sean comparadas dentro del script, no olvides que a fin de cuentas es texto y debe estar encomillado correctamente. Por otro lado, tienes `header()` que o bien en una función definida por ti y que no has compartido para que podamos evaluar, o bien has confundido con la función del mismo nombre de PHP, en cuyo caso bajo ningún concepto se va a ejecutar.

Comment: Muchas gracias por los consejos saludos !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No necesitas la funcion en js si usas la etiqueta  puedes hacer:

```html
<div class="col-md-4 top-header-middle">
  <a href="<?php echo ($_SESSION['tper1'] === 'admin') ? './administrador.php' : './tienda.php' ?>" ><img src="img/1.png" alt="" width="80%"/></a>
</div>
```

Si solo hay dos tipos de usuario tambien puedes omitir la validacion ya que si no es admin es usuario regular.

si tuvieras mas de un usuario puedes crear un switch.

saludos

Comment: Sergio Cauich muchas gracias por tu respuesta era justo lo que estaba buscando me ayudo bastante tu aporte.  De nuevo gracias y saludos!!

Answer (score 0):

1. Usa echo para imprimir tus resultados. (o print)

Poniendo solo un String no vas a hacer nada, necesitar mostrarlo.

2. Lo unico que necesitas imprimir es la url.

Por lo tanto, la funcion de recolocacion deberia ir fuera. De todas maneras echale un vistazo, con location solo no vas a ningun lado.

Y por último, yo la validacion la haria por PHP, ya que js lo puedes ver, y sabriamos a donde redirige cada una de las cosas.

```
<div class="col-md-4 top-header-middle">
  <a href="#" onclick="direc();"><img src="img/1.png" alt="" width="80%"/></a>
  <script>
    function direc(){
      location.replace(
        if("<?php echo($_SESSION["tper1"]);?>" === "admin"){
          echo("./administrador.php");
        }
        else("<?php echo$_SESSION["tper1"]);?>" === "client"){
          echo("./tienda.php");
        }
      );
    }
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: ok muchas gracias por tu aporte GDP lo de cambiar JS por PHP era algo que no tomaba en cuenta pero ahora que lo se lo voy hacer gracias!!! Saludos.